# How to upgrade Oracle apex workspace to 20.1 latest version

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-19.1

As we know 20.1 is launched on 23rd april.

I tried to download it but i am using apex.oracle.com for learning. How do i upgrade that to 20.1?

I downloaded the 20.1 set up but cannot understand how to install/upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood the question, you'd want to upgrade Apex version which you use on apex.oracle.com.

If that's so, no - you can't do that. Oracle guys will do it when they find appropriate. Usually there's a notice on that site about "scheduled maintenance" or something like that.

Comment: oh, thats bad. actually a new ticketing app has been introduced and i needed that. By any chance can i get the source code of the new app?

Comment: @Vini: that would be a question for Oracle.

Comment: Well, you could install the latest Apex version into **your own** database ... or wait for a while. As far as I can tell, apex.oracle.com is upgraded soon after the newest version is released.

Answer (score 2):

apex.oracle.com is managed by Oracle and is always upgraded to a pre-release version of Oracle APEX prior to the full public release of APEX.  As of this writing (April 26, 2020), apex.oracle.com is already upgraded to production APEX 20.1.

If you wish to download the latest version of APEX for on-premises installation, you can simply go to https://apex.oracle.com/download.